# Problems with dynamic multiobject property name in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This will be tuff because I don't really know how to ask the right question. So, I have an object with the following structure:

[image]

When I do:

`console.info(myObject.StackPaneProvider)`

I get the expected result:
[image]

But if I try to  access it dynamically with

```
var key = "StackPaneProvider";
console.info(myObj.key);
```

(actually the key variable is generated dynamically, and it is of type string) I get "undefined" in Firebug. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var key = "StackPaneProvider";
console.info(myObj[key]);
```

You want to use `[key]` for example

```
myObj.StackPaneProvider === myObj["StackPaneProvider"];
myObj.key === myObj["key"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  accessing key using myObj[key]?

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is
    myObj[key]